# how to avoid spark NumberFormatException: null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I have a general question derived from the specific exception I have encountered.

I'm querying data with dataproc using spark 1.6. I need to get 1 day of data (~10000 files) from 2 logs and then do some transformations.

However, my data may (or may not) have some bad data
after not succeeding in a full day query, I tried hour 00-09 and got no error. tried hour 10-19 and got an exception. tried hour by hour and found out that the bad data is in hour:10. hour 11 and 12 were fine

basically my code is:

```
val imps = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").option("inferSchema", "true").load("gs://logs.xxxx.com/2016/03/14/xxxxx/imps/2016-03-14-10*").select("C0","C18","C7","C9","C33","C29","C63").registerTempTable("imps")

val conv = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").option("inferSchema", "true").load("gs://logs.xxxx.com/2016/03/14/xxxxx/conv/2016-03-14-10*").select("C0","C18","C7","C9","C33","C29","C65").registerTempTable("conversions")

val ff = sqlContext.sql("select * from (select * from imps) A inner join (select * from conversions) B on A.C0=B.C0 and A.C7=B.C7 and A.C18=B.C18 ").coalesce(16).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("gs://xxxx-spark-results/newSparkResults/Plara2.6Mar14_10_1/")
```

{over - simplified}

the error I get is:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 38 in stage 130.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 38.3 in stage 130.0 (TID 88495, plara26-0317-0001-sw-v8oc.c.xxxxx-analytics.internal): java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)
    at com.databricks.spark.csv.util.TypeCast$.castTo(TypeCast.scala:53)
    at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$6.apply(CsvRelation.scala:181)
    at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$6.apply(CsvRelation.scala:162)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.processInputs(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:511)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.<init>(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

so my question is - how to implement an exception handling USING spark-csv ?
I can convert the dataframe to RDD and work on it there but it seems there must be a better way.....

anyone solved a similar problem?

Comment: update: I've been able to get my data right after changing the option to infer schema to false. this way the fields are read as strings and the conversion to Int is of course unnecessary. 
I'm still looking for a robust solution for catching exceptions.....

Answer (score 0):

This is because inferring automatically the schema is not safe against invalid data from your input files.

This can cause the dataframe schema to be different, when using different input files.

Suppose we have a csv file with floats, contaminated with a string:

```
0.018
0.095
0.000
'hoi'
0.000
0.093
0.012
```

When we read this into a dataframe using *inferSchema*, like so:

```
>>> df = spark.read.format('csv').option('inferSchema', True).load('./test_csv.dat')
>>> df.show()
+-----+
|  _c0|
+-----+
|0.018|
|0.095|
|0.000|
|'hoi'|
|0.000|
|0.093|
|0.012|
+-----+
```

then the type is not properly inferred:

```
>>> df.schema
StructType(List(StructField(_c0,StringType,true)))
```

You can solve this by manually casting the column, like so:

```
>>> df = df.withColumn('val_float', df_tmp._c0.cast(FloatType())).select('val_float')
>>> df.show()
+---------+
|val_float|
+---------+
|    0.018|
|    0.095|
|      0.0|
|     null|
|      0.0|
|    0.093|
|    0.012|
+---------+

>>> df.schema
StructType(List(StructField(val_float,FloatType,true)))
```